# What is the term (if any) used for writing a script which interacts with a webpage that I am viewing as a client

Tags: javascript, scripting, webserver

I want to write some JavaScript to do some repetitive tasks in Umbraco (a CMS), wondering what the specific term I should be searching to find some resources.

As an example: 
Say I had a list of links:

Page 1

```
Foo

foo

foobar

barfoo
```

And for each link I had to click it and enter the same word into an input field called name

Page 2

```
link = Foo
        ___________________
Name:  |________Jon________|
```

Go back to Page 1, click next link and repeat until end

iMacros is a great example of what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use JavaScript. You'd list to events generated from the ContentService save the field accordingly.
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/ContentService-Events

Alternatively you might create a custom property editor that defaults to the name of the page if nothing else is added
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/

Alternatively, alternatively, you'd just leave the field in question blank and handle blank entries at the point of use (e.g. if blank then use Name)

You could potentially use JavaScript by creating a plugin in App_Plugins with a package.manifest to add in your own custom JavaScript file into the BackOffice, but this would be a bit of a hack and i'm not sure how easy it would be to achieve what you're after.